# How to use accordion with a table angular2

Tags: angular, accordion

I am trying to use accordion and have no idea how to use it with table.

I have a table and in that table I am getting records form my component and displaying them using `*ngFor`. Now on click of a row I need to replace that row with another component so I am trying to use accordion for that.

**sample**:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index">
            <td>{{game.date}}</td>
            <td>{{game.label}}</td>
            <td>{{game.score}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is a simple table and on click of any row I want to replace that row with a praticular content.

**sample accordion** I need to use in table:

```
<accordion>
        <accordion-group heading="About me">
            <app-member></app-member>
        </accordion-group>
        <accordion-group>
            <accordion-heading>
                Custom heading
            </accordion-heading>
            <app-member></app-member>           
        </accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Any idea How can I use accordion for this ?
Thanks

Comment: where is accordion in your code?

Comment: I want to use it but have no idea how to use it ... can post simple accordion

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I have added sample code for accordion .. Please look into this

Comment: Could you implement https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion ?
This accordion module will help to reduce much of your code

Comment: check this implementation https://stackblitz.com/edit/stack-table

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of simple CSS and make it simple.

**HTML**

```
   <table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index" [ngClass]="{activetab: isActive(game.label)}">
            <div (click)="getSub(game.label);">
                <!-- use the uniqueId here  -->
                <td>{{game.date}}</td>
                <td>{{game.label}}</td>
                <td>{{game.score}}</td>
            </div>
            <table>
                <tbody [ngClass]="{activetab: isActive(game.label)}">
                    <tr *ngFor="let subgame of game.sub">
                        <td>{{subgame.date}}</td>
                        <td>{{subgame.label}}</td>
                        <td>{{subgame.score}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
tr .activetab {
    display: block !important;
}
```

**TS**

```
      isActive(id) {
        return this.selected === id;
      }

     getSub(id) {
   //TODO//
    this.selected = (this.selected === id ? null : id);
  }
```

I think this should work fine.

EDIT: You can refer the same example on https://plnkr.co/edit/B66nuR?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but what I need to do is I need to open another component on click of a table row and I will hide that row ... Basically it is an edit form ..when ever any row will be clicked .. A new component will be displayed to edit 
 and I will pass some data with that component ..

Comment: what kind of component do you need to open? and is it depending on the row that is being clicked?

Comment: yes It will be a form And In that form will display all the fields selected in the row

Comment: Yes, you can still use the same code, instead of the table tag inside the row you can provide your component (I assume that it will take input and forms are build inside the component).